# How many Dyck paths start from $(x, y)$?

Tags: combinatorics

Dyck paths count paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ in steps going east $(1,0)$ or north $(0,1)$ and that remain below the diagonal.

How many of these pass starts from given point $(x,y)$ with $x \leq y$?

Note that, I found the similar question, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64664/how-many-dyck-paths-pass-through-x-y), but my question is **starting from** $(x,y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the question that you are citing, they find the number of Dyck paths that go from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ that pass thru the point $(y,x).$(is backwards because they are doing it there above the diagonal). They (Brian M. Scott) find  that this is
$$\begin{align*}
&\frac{x+1-y}{x+1}\binom{x+y}{x} \cdot \frac{x+1-y}{n+1-y}\binom{2n-x-y}{n-y} =\\
&\frac{(x+1-y)^2}{(x+1)(n+1-y)} \binom{2n-(x+y)}{n-x} \binom{x+y}{x}.
\end{align*}.$$
Notice that a path here is any path going from $(0,0)$ to $(y,x)$ and then a path from $(y,x)$ to $(n,n).$ It is also shown there that the number of paths that go from $(0,0)$ to $(y,x)$ is $\frac{x+1-y}{x+1}\binom{x+y}{x}$ and hence if you divide the answer by this, you will get the number of paths that start at $(y,x)$ to $(n,n).$

Namely, $$\frac{(y-x+1)}{(n+1-x)}\binom{2n-(x+y)}{n-y}$$
is the answer to your problem.